# FFMPEG - ffprobe stuck after reaching h264 step on window server

Tags: ffmpeg, video, ffprobe

I am using Xabe/ffmpeg in c# to forward a stream from a camera ip to an api clients.
On local: everything works fine.

On the api server (where the conversion is done), targeting the same camera: I have an error "Invalid file". I investigate a bit, and found that xabe/ffmpeg use ffprobe to get the media info, and when doing this, return the error.

I tried to run this command to see what happen behind Xabe/ffmpeg code:

```
 ffprobe -loglevel repeat+48 rtsp://user:password@cameraIp/axis-media/media.amp
```

When I run this command, here is the result:

```
ffprobe version 2022-01-13-git-c936c319bd-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 18.100 / 57. 18.100
  libavcodec     59. 20.100 / 59. 20.100
  libavformat    59. 17.100 / 59. 17.100
  libavdevice    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavfilter     8. 25.100 /  8. 25.100
  libswscale      6.  5.100 /  6.  5.100
  libswresample   4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libpostproc    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
[tcp @ 00000254c6f9fd80] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 00000254c6f9fd80] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 00000254c6f9fd80] Address 10.XXX.XXX.XXX port 554
[tcp @ 00000254c6f9fd80] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 00000254c6f9fd80] Address 10.XXX.XXX.XXX port 554
[tcp @ 00000254c6f9fd80] Starting connection attempt to 10.XXX.XXX.XXX port 554
[tcp @ 00000254c6f9fd80] Successfully connected to 10.XXX.XXX.XXX port 554
[rtsp @ 00000254c53290c0] SDP:
v=0
o=- 4002621882817261199 1 IN IP4 10.XXX.XXX.XXX
s=Session streamed with GStreamer
i=rtsp-server
t=0 0
a=tool:GStreamer
a=type:broadcast
a=range:npt=now-
a=control:rtsp://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:554/axis-media/media.amp
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:50000
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640029;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAKa0AxSAUAKGwFuAgIDSDxIio,aO48sA==
a=control:rtsp://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:554/axis-media/media.amp/stream=0
a=framerate:13.000000
a=transform:1.000000,0.000000,0.000000;0.000000,1.000000,0.000000;0.000000,0.000000,1.000000

[rtsp @ 00000254c53290c0] video codec set to: h264
[rtsp @ 00000254c53290c0] RTP Packetization Mode: 1
[rtsp @ 00000254c53290c0] RTP Profile IDC: 64 Profile IOP: 0 Level: 29
[rtsp @ 00000254c53290c0] Extradata set to 00000254c6fa5080 (size: 33)
[rtp @ 00000254c6fa2780] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000254c6fa2840] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000254c6fa2840] end receive buffer size reported is 393216
[udp @ 00000254c6fa2940] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 00000254c6fa2940] end receive buffer size reported is 393216
[rtsp @ 00000254c53290c0] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[rtsp @ 00000254c53290c0] hello state=0
[h264 @ 00000254c6fa4b40] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000254c6fa4b40] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
```

After this line, nothing happen. No error, no prompt. I can only cancel the task with ctrl+c.

I looked in the ffprobe documentation, but could not find anything about similar case.
This could be the cause of the error returned by Xabe/ffmpeg.

Someone have an idea to solve, debug, find something? Is Ffmpeg compatible on windows server ?

***EDIT***

I tried to bypass ffprobe by specifying the format of the stream but same thing happen: ffmpeg is stuck after reaching `[h264 @ 00000254c6fa4b40] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a total of two days searching: The problem was that the protocol udp was not allowed on server. Only TCP was. The solution:

Add:

> -rtsp_transport tcp

So the command line look like:

```
ffprobe -loglevel repeat+48 -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://user:password@cameraIp/axis-media/media.amp
```

Comment: You are a savior. I've been dealing with a similar issue, I had two videos one `mp4a` and one `avc1` and running ffprobe for the second one just hangs forever, adding tcp flag fixed it.